# Separate Text files from List into GUI Labels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code allows .txt files to be read and placed into a GUI Label and then displayed as on screen text. So far the txt files are placed into a List and then a `foreach` then assigns the variable. However, My problem is both text files are appearing together in each label rather than separately and I was wondering how would this be done?
powersupply.txt is for the powersupply model and puzzles.txt is for the cdrw model. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
// To use List
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    string cdrw = "CD-RW";
    string powerSupply = "Power Supply";
    public string txt;
    public static string completeText = "";
    public GameObject cdrwModel;
    public GameObject powerSupplyModel;
    public StreamReader reader = null;
    public FileInfo theSourceFile = null
    private static List<string> _allFiles = new List<string>();

    public void Start()
    {
        theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
        ProcessFile(theSourceFile);
        theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/powersupply.txt");
        ProcessFile(theSourceFile);
    }

    private void ProcessFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.Exists)
            reader = file.OpenText();
        if (reader == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
        }
        else
        {
            while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
                completeText += txt + "\n";
            }
            _allFiles.Add(completeText);     
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if ((isClicked) && (cdrwModel))
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                foreach (var file in _allFiles)
                {
                    GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), file);
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((isClicked) && (powerSupplyModel))
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                foreach (var file in _allFiles)
                {
                    GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are reading both files into _allFiles and then reading the whole content to both labels..?

Comment: Yes, how would I separate the content into both Labels?

Comment: One option would be to create separate string variable or List<string> if you like for each label... So you would load one string to one label..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 2 references to the same completeText string to _allFiles, any changes made after you add the first instance will be seen in that entry to the list as it is a reference to the same object. You need to create a new instance each time you want to add different text. You could make completeText a local variable to ProcessFile.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Is there any way you could possibly show me as I am sort of new to all this? :)

Comment: Delete the _public static string completeText = "";"_ line AND add a local declaration in the ProcessFile method :
_"private void ProcessFile(FileInfo file)
    { string completeText = ""; ....."_

Comment: Okay brilliant! I did that and now the text is just appearing on top of eachother?

Comment: I think that is because all of your Rectangles are in the same place, they need either the x or y parameter changing each time round the loop : int x = 0; foreach (var file in _allFiles)
{
GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
GUI.Label(new Rect(1000 + (x * 410), 50, 400, 400), file); x++;
}  - I've multiplied by 410 because of width of rectangle + given it 10 spacing.

Comment: But I mean - The two text files are still appearing in the same label rather than one text file for one label and another text file for the other?

Comment: So for example if I hover over the cdrw model "puzzles.txt" appears and nothing else and then when I hover over the power supply model "powersupply.txt" appears and nothing else :/